# Get current time at end of month with moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to get exact same time (current time) when user performs action but the date should be end date of month. 
I have tried moment().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') but all format gives 23:59:59 only. I want to get current time. how will i be able to get that ?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: So when i use endOf() it gives me 2019-09-30T23:59:59+05:30 i want something like this 2019-09-30T11:42:18+05:30 which has endOf month ie 30 sept and exact same time as current.

Comment: I think she is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
moment().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' ' + moment().format('hh:mm:ss')
```

Comment: moment().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' T' + moment().format('hh:mm:ssZ')

Answer (score 0):

You can just get only date of end Date of month using
`moment().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD')`
then get current Time using moment like this
`moment(new Date()).format('HH:MM:SS')`

then concat both to get your desired output

`moment().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' ' + moment(new Date()).format('HH:MM:SS')`

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24068335).

Answer (score 0):

`moment().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')` provides you the last second of the month.

Since you are expecting the month end date and current time, so you have to concat the current time with end date of the month

```js
const result = moment().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' ' 
    + moment().format('HH:MM:SS')
    
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want the current time shifted to the end of month. To do this, simply manipulate via [`.date()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/):

```
function atEndOfMonth() {
    let now = moment()
    let endOfMonth = moment(now).endOf('month')

    return now.date(endOfMonth.date())
}
```